# UI-Router : Hide one view and display another based on some condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
 <div id="documentView" class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div ui-view="productView"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- detail page implementation -->  
    <div ui-view="detailView"></div>
```

I want to hide productview and display detailview based on some condition.

```
  .state('app.sr.product', {
            name: 'product info',
            url: '/product/:productRef/:productSerialNumber',
            views: {
                "rootContainer": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/product/product.html',
                    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                },
                "productDetails@app.sr.product": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/product/product-details.html',
                    //controller: 'ProductCtrl', // herited from parent !
                    //controllerAs: 'vm'
                },
                "productView@app.sr.product": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/product/product-documents.html',
                    //controller: 'ProductCtrl',
                    //controllerAs: 'vm'
                },
                "detailView@app.sr.product": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/detail/detail1.html',
                    controller: 'DetailCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
```

Above is my state manager file, but I am not getting the way how to achieve it, hiding one view based on some condition and display another.

Basically Productview is formed on the basis of some directive and  it display one table , it display some hyperlinks inside row.I want when user clicks on those hyperlinks it will take me to detail page and hide the table that is productview.

Comment: `ng-if` and some parent scope variable to keep / update the flag(s)?

Comment: Can you provide some code or fiddler , will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Use an ng-if based on your conditions so your div tag would look like this:

```
 <div ui-view="productView" ng-if="someCondition">
 <div ui-view="detailView" ng-if="otherCondition">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i cannot accept the answer because its too let for me to test. I don't have the code with me now